# duplicate rows from foreach using php

Tags: php

i have output from query

```
object(stdClass)#14 (6) {
  ["aid"]=>
  string(2) "11"
  ["bid"]=>
  string(2) "34"
  ["colorname"]=>
  string(6) "Silver"
  ["colorgroupname"]=>
  string(15) "LIGHT AQUA OPAL"
  ["colorcode"]=>
  string(3) "6M8"
  ["brand"]=>
  string(6) "Car"
}
```

but after loop in foreach

complite code what i use and i use var_dump to display output i get one rows but after loop i get 6 duplicate rows.

```
function ViewDBGridColorfinder($header,$DBG_control,$parameters)
    {
        $rows = $this->select_join_by(index_join_ColorFinder,TBL_COLOR,tbl_join_ColorFinder,where_by,order_by_dbgrid,$parameters);

        $table = new Generator_Table($header);
        //var_dump($rows);

        if (is_array($rows) || is_object($rows))
        {
            foreach($rows as $val)
            {
                $DetailColor = '<a href="#PopColor" onclick="showdetail('.$rows->bid.')" data-toggle="modal">'.$rows->colorname.'</a>';
                $table->addCell($DetailColor);
                $table->addCell($rows->colorcode);
                $table->addCell($rows->brand);
                $table->addCell($rows->colorgroupname);
                $table->addCell(str_replace('onclick=""',"onclick=DelRow(".$rows->aid.")",$DBG_control));
            }
        }
        $DBGrid_data = $table->generate();

        return $DBGrid_data;
    }
```

the result to be duplicate.

where is the error?

Comment: Looks like you confuse `$rows` with `$val` in your loop. But even then the code looks "surprising".

Comment: if i use $val i get notice : : Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: If `$rows` is an object...  just remove the foreach statement and keep the rest as is..

Comment: Then you need to sort out what `"rows` actually contained. Please edit your question and explain that. Where is the connection to the object notation above?

Comment: A string? So what is the "output from query" then? I think you need to post more code since it's not obvious what you are doing between the query and the loop. And if it is a string, none of your code should work?

Comment: i update the script in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this sholud only do for you

```
$DetailColor = '<a href="#PopColor" onclick="showdetail('.$rows->bid.')" data-toggle="modal">'.$rows->colorname.'</a>';
 $table->addCell($DetailColor);
 $table->addCell($rows->colorcode);
 $table->addCell($rows->brand);
 $table->addCell($rows->colorgroupname);

 $table->addCell(str_replace('onclick=""',"onclick=DelRow(".$rows->aid.")",$DBG_control));
```

Remove foreach as.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all `$rows` with `$val` in foreach loop

Comment: if i use $val i get notice : Trying to get property of non-object in

Answer (score 0):

You used the variable $rows itself instead of $val. Update the code like this:

```
foreach($rows as $val)
{
  $DetailColor = '<a href="#PopColor" onclick="showdetail('.$val->bid.')" data-toggle="modal">'.$val->colorname.'</a>';
  $table->addCell($DetailColor);
  $table->addCell($val->colorcode);
  $table->addCell($val->brand);
  $table->addCell($val->colorgroupname);
  $table->addCell(str_replace('onclick=""',"onclick=DelRow(".$val->aid.")",$DBG_control));
}
```

Comment: if i use $val i get notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Answer (score 0):

Your `$row` is an object. So you don't really need to **forloop** inside the object. The reason why your getting 6 records is because there are six elements inside your object.

Count this and see, There are 6 elements(aid,bid,colorname,colorgroupname,colorcode,brand):

```
object(stdClass)#14 (6) {
  ["aid"]=>
  string(2) "11"
  ["bid"]=>
  string(2) "34"
  ["colorname"]=>
  string(6) "Silver"
  ["colorgroupname"]=>
  string(15) "LIGHT AQUA OPAL"
  ["colorcode"]=>
  string(3) "6M8"
  ["brand"]=>
  string(6) "Car"
}
```

So for each element, it will add the cell.In PHP you can use the `->` to access the elements inside the object. Modify the code this way:

```
 if (is_array($rows) || is_object($rows))
        {

            $DetailColor = '<a href="#PopColor" onclick="showdetail('.$rows->bid.')" data-toggle="modal">'.$rows->colorname.'</a>';
            $table->addCell($DetailColor);
            $table->addCell($rows->colorcode);
            $table->addCell($rows->brand);
            $table->addCell($rows->colorgroupname);
            $table->addCell(str_replace('onclick=""',"onclick=DelRow(".$rows->aid.")",$DBG_control));
    }
```